# Unable to understand graphs created by Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Im trying to understand the graphing functionality that Grafana and Prometheus use. If I select a Counter, for example, `http_requests_total`. On the "table" tab of the Prometheus dashboard on my server, I get latest result, 7655. If I select the "Graph" tab, then I get a graph with varying data points that plots  7060 a few ms before the last time, (ie. when I ran the query). Then a few ms before that, I noticed the number is actually higher than the current value. This also is reflects in Grafana with the same query. Im not using rate/increase yet, Im just trying to understand the basics. But I have learned that Counters do not decrease, so aside from being given values higher than what is current, I find it off that the Counter decreases in the "Graph" tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading [key concepts for Prometheus and VictoriaMetrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/) in order to better understand how Grafana works with Prometheus. The following chapters are the most important:

- [data model](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#data-model)
- [metric types](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#types-of-metrics)
- [instant query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#instant-query) and [range query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#range-query)
- [time series filtering](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#filtering)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. I was using a non-default metric that was not configured to use a muli-processing environment. The application is FASTAPI using node_exporter, and `prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator`. Basically, original configuration was pulling different metrics from different workers, causing extremely confusing results. Answered here, [Unable to calculate increase/rate of http requests accurately using Prometheus in Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78017843/unable-to-calculate-increase-rate-of-http-requests-accurately-using-prometheus-i/78028725#78028725)