# Unable to calculate increase/rate of http requests accurately using Prometheus in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Note the test conditions below were used with apache bench, testing 100 concurrent requests.

**Bottom graph: [CPU USAGE]** is the desired visualation result. A "sloping" increment/decrement. I am seeing "high load" at specific point, which can easily be inferred from the graph. The query being used to calculate CPU Usage is `100 - (avg by (cpu) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[30s])) * 100)`. "step/res" is set to "auto".

**Top Graph: [http_requests_total]** DOES NOT accurately reflect the high load event occurred in the same instant as the CPU usage does. Nor does the graph really even make sense. The expression use on this graph is `irate(http_requests_total{handler!~'none|/metrics'}[5m]`.step/"data resoltuion" of this expression is set to 30s (if this is set to auto, the variation is even worse)

Both scrape intervals are set to 15s.

For some reason, I have been unable to get the http_requests_total (Top Graph) or any http_* counter metric to reflect the same pattern. What I find confusing is that BOTH of the metrics are of the data tpye Counter, yet looking at the graph both imply 2 different scenarios. Bottom graph implies that one high load event ocurred, top graph implies there are continuous high request events.

End goal: I dont need an exact number of HTTP requests made, I would just like to see data points plotted for `http_requests_total` (Top Graph) in a way that actually reflects what happened. 100 concurrent requests were made at once, and then no more.

EDIT:
Application:

- FASTAPI (deployed Gunicorn w/ multiple workers)

Metrics Exporters:

- Node Exporter ("plugin" from Prometheus) - used to get CPU Usage
- `prometheus-fastapi-exporter` in Python - used to get HTTP requests

[image]
[image]

Comment: You want to say, that you expect top graph to have a single spike, similar to CPU one, and then basically no activity?

Comment: Correct. I will probably switch to using VictoriaMetrics because it seems like its much easier, but I find it hard to accept that irate ( or Promethues in general) cannot semi-accurately portray a "high load" condition. Since Im using `irate` in the CPU usage to calculate percent, it seems like it COULD work. Im just not sure what I am doing wrong. I dont need EXACT numbers, just like to see a "simple" graph that doesnt requires so much intuition to decude what's actually ocurring.

Comment: I don't think `irate` has anything to do with you problem. Your problem shows something very strange, and I seriously recommend investigating your data (values of the metric without irate, for starters).

Answer (score 1):

thanks @markalex, a few things to note.

There are furhter configuration requirements when running a Python FastAPI application using the `fastapi-prometheus-instrumentator` pkg to expose metrics. Here's what happened.

1. Just a heads up, part of my confusion was, despite the docs providing an [example](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/) on how to run a query. **THIS METRIC DOES NOT EXIST BY DEFAULT**. I feel like they could have specified that, or maybe they did and I over looked it. The reason I am able to query this is via the `prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator` pkg which automatically creates this metric.
2. It turns out that others have noticed [a strange drop in counters](https://github.com/trallnag/prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator/issues/50) which **WILL** happen if your using mutiple Gunircorn workers which I was. The pkg `prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator` which build upon `prometheus_client` so all I needed to do was create a directory (arbitrary), and then assign the directory to the environment variable `PROMETHEUS_MULTIPROC_DIR` and voila! Accurate metrics!

Hopefully this helps someone else notice this issue. In the end, the prometheus docs nor docs for `prometheus-fastapi-interumentator` make no mention of configuring your environment correctly if running multiple processes or possible caveats.

Comment: Updated comment. If you have any suggestions I can fix it. The issue was basically assumptions and configuration. Because I had the metric avaiable, that was used in the querying example, I was expecting an result "that made sense" But there was more to the configuration that was never mentioned in the Python library.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [irate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#irate) doesn't capture spikes - it selects a subset of [raw samples](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#raw-samples) on the given look behind window in square brackets and then calculates the increase rate over these samples. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.

P.S. If you want reliably capturing increase rate spikes on any time ranges and any look behind windows, then try [rollup_rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#rollup_rate) function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've read alot of your posts actually, including the link to the article. My issue is that this is the same behaviour for rate/increase too, but only for the http_requests_* metric. I understand `irate` basically takes the last 2 samples, and `rate` is an avg of `increase`, but  `irate` and cpu usage work EXACTLY as expected and is the desired behaviour. Is that because changes to CPU usage are "slower"/less sporadic than requests? But they are both counters with the same scrape intervals., and there are literally 0  http_requests that follow intended spike

Comment: Probably, the `http_requests_*` [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#counter) changes slowly compared to CPU usage counter. In this case Prometheus may return unexpected results because of extrapolation. See https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746 . VictoriaMetrics is free from this issue - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/